# How to increase base device size per container?

Tags: arch-linux, docker

While building a container (the same happens when I just run the same commands inside a container) I've run into an error complaining about "no space left on device". I checked with `df` and confirmed that I have enough space. My OS is Arch Linux, here is output of `docker info`:

```
[mark@arch stackage-head]$ docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 123
Server Version: 18.03.0-ce
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-8:3-5898903-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Data Space Used: 45.27GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4GB
 Data Space Available: 56.87GB
 Metadata Space Used: 36.01MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.111GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74GB
 Deferred Removal Enabled: true
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: true
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Library Version: 1.02.146 (2017-12-18)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: cfd04396dc68220d1cecbe686a6cc3aa5ce3667c
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.15.11-1-ARCH
Operating System: Arch Linux
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 15.58GiB
Name: arch
ID: VKYM:3FM2:MAE7:SZPY:E4CR:6U6K:Z5SG:5A66:NEJT:K4MD:LN57:FBXM
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Username: mrkkrp
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: devicemapper: usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use.
         Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
```

I tried using the `--storage-opt size=20G` option but it fails like so:

```
[mark@arch stackage-head]$ docker run -it --storage-opt size=20G snoyberg/stackage:nightly bash
docker: Error response from daemon: Failed to grow rootfs:exit status 1:xfs_growfs: /dev/mapper/docker-8:3-5898903-3456c9ee1d5a83fc705125974101c89015562d0cc4c00bc5e1c97bd560dded6a-init is not a mounted XFS filesystem.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

As per [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-storage-driver-options-per-container) this should work.

I checked Arch Linux wiki, which has a relevant section:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Docker#Failed_to_create_some.2Fpath.2Fto.2Ffile:_No_space_left_on_device

However I'm not sure how this applies to me because I don't have XFS filesystem mounted in `/etc/fstab`, as I understand `devicemapper` creates them as needed for containers.

A container cannot grow larger than this "base device size" so I tried to increase it in various ways.

- With `docker daemon --storage-opt dm.basesize=20G` as per [this oldish post](https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2016/03/daemon_option_basedevicesize/). Alas, `--storage-opt` is reported as an unknown flag.
- By passing `--storage-opt dm.basesize=20G` to `docker run`, but this time `dm.basesize` is reported as an unknown option.

Answer (score 0):

> However I'm not sure how this applies to me because I don't have XFS filesystem mounted in /etc/fstab, as I understand devicemapper creates them as needed for containers.

You're certainely right but we can see that in your "Docker Info" that the "Backing Filesystem: xfs". It means that docker uses xfs for container base volume on the fly created in the volume "docker-8:3-5898903-pool"

The option "--storage-opt size=20G" works for me.

I think that your docker reserved storage volume didn't have enough of space to grow.

Please post results of following commands:

1. lsblk
2. List item
3. lvs
4. vgs

Answer (score 0):

Be carrefull when using loops with selinux in an other mode than disabled.

If your not aware with SELinux, test with disabled mode ([using this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SELinux)) and learn about SELinux in docker to configure it correctly ([Docker SELinux Security Policy](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/container_security_guide/docker_selinux_security_policy)).

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the links for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [Please review the Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information regarding this. Thank you!